# Can I create custom methods in Backbone.collections?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

Apologies I'm still learning the fundamentals of Backbone.

I'm a little confused about Backbone.collections. I understand that they consist of a group of collections, and can have url and model attributes. Can you define a custom method in a backbone.collection?

For example:

```
var Books = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/books',
    model: Book,
    getBook: function(id, options){
                  ......
            }
});
```

Is this possible and if so, what would it do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is absolutely possible and a great way to encapsulate functionality specific to that collection. Although typically in practice I find myself expanding the functionality of the Models more.

As far as what it would do... If you had a collection of books you may want to write helper methods for accessing, pruning, or serializing your collection. I'm not sure what your business needs are.

Have look at [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) for available collection functions, so you don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Or if you'd like to have another option instead underscore.. take a look on Lo-Dash, http://lodash.com/ I prefer lodash.

Comment: I second the lo-dash recommendation

Answer (score 0):

Custom methods on collections would usually do one of two things:

1. Handle events fired by the models, if you need to trigger custom actions when that happens
2. Hold reusable looping/filtering/sorting so that you don't have to inline that stuff throughout your application

When I say collections would usually do this, it doesn't necessarily mean that you're doing anything wrong if your methods falls outside of these two categories, this is just to get an idea what kind of logic you might want to put into a collection custom method.

Take your books for instance, let's say you wanted to have a custom method that returns the total number of pages for all of the books in your collection. That could look something like this:

```
var Books = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/books',
    model: Book,
    getTotalNumPages: function() {
        var numPages = 0;
        this.each(function(model) {
            numPages += parseInt(model.get("pageCount"), 10);
        });
        return numPages;
    }
});


// Elsewhere in your app
console.log("Total pages: ", books.getTotalNumPages());
```